# Update ProgressDialog in Timer Task in android

Tags: android

I use this code to update progress dialog in a thread But doesn't work! Progress stay in 0%. 
I saw **AsyncTask** codes But I want to do it by my code. How should I do it?

```
final Timer timer=new Timer();
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progress.setProgress((j/342)*100);

            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 50);
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: is j updated its value?

Comment: yes, But j update in other thread

Comment: try using atomic integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's caused by the int/int division. Since you're calculating the percentage, it's safe to assume the result before multiplication is always < 1 and will be truncated as it is casted to int, giving you 0*100 for all the values of j below 342.

Try this:

```
progress.setProgress((int)(((float)j/342)*100));
```